# what is the alternative for HTML5 Date field for older browsers?

Tags: html5

Older IE and firefox doesn't supports HTML5 date field or email field. is there any alternate solution ?

Comment: This is an implementation topic, it's not really on-topic for User Experience. A variety on this question has been asked and answered on StackOverflow here: [Is there a string format of Date that works in all browsers and all localities?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9363270/is-there-a-string-format-of-date-that-works-in-all-browsers-and-all-localities)

Comment: This is a very important question. We have a crusty in house javascript Date calendar widget and would like to replace it with an open library for non-HTML5 browsers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are talking about input field types then for old IE just use type="text".

Date field. In Chrome it allows you to select a date using inbuilt calendar. Alternative for inbuilt calendar is jQuery [datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/)

Email field in Chrome has inbuilt validation, use jQuery for [email validation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/email).

Comment: See here. HTML5 with jQuery fallback: http://webdevhub.co.uk/native-html5-datepicker-with-a-javascript-fallback/